# Mock JSONP request with nock (React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, redux

I am writing unit tests for Redux actions, and one of them contains JSONP request, code:

```
export function performUsersRequest() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestUser());

        return fetchJsonp(APP_CONFIG.URL)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(requestUserFulfilled());
                return res.json()
            })
            .catch(ex => {
                dispatch(requestUserRejected());
            })
    }
}
```

Because of it is JSONP request, looks like [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) library can't mock it and I always get request rejected action. I've tried to find a solution, but have not ended up with something useful. My test is:

```
it('make async request to get users', () => {
    const store = mockStore({getUsers: ''});
    const dispatch = store.dispatch;

    nock(APP_CONFIG.URL)
        .get('/')
        .reply(200, {users: []});

    return dispatch(actionsUsers.performUserRequest())
        .then(() => {
            console.log(store.getActions());
            // expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        })

});
```